# Tcpdump doesn't work in vlan

Tags: tcpdump

I got a pcap file captured from vlan. 
I want to filter some packets out of that file with Tcpdump, but it doesn't work.

Is it because Tcpdump doesn't support vlan?
As it works for the pcap file captured int normal ethernet.

Answer (score 5):

If the packet contains a 802.1q vlan tag, you can do the following -

tcpdump -s0 -nnpi eth0 vlan 100

where 100 is the vlan id.

You've to be a bit careful with the vlan keyword as a BPF filter (when combining it with other filters), as it moves filters 4 bytes to the right, see here - http://www.christian-rossow.de/articles/tcpdump_filter_mixed_tagged_and_untagged_VLAN_traffic.php.

You could also use a filter of the ethernet header - this link describes the solution and potential issues perfectly -

https://serverfault.com/questions/196250/tcpdump-capture-one-of-several-vlans.